# Wrapping web pages in web app using Cordova

Tags: cordova

I need to know whether it is possible to use the Cordova tool for my project. I have no experience with it and need a basic information about what is possible to do with it.

I need to create a  mobile application that would show a certain static webpage (start.html) embedded in the app after the app gets started. That page would contain a link to some URL on the web (e.g. somemysite.com). When the user clicks the link on the phone inside of the app the app would display the content of somemysite.com. That page can have links to further other pages. The page somemysite.com would contain a special link (e.g. localhost address or so) that would point to the embedded page start.html. After clicking that link the app would again display the embedded page on the display.

I did not start exploring the Cordova tool yet but I do not want to invest my time into it before I know it allows to do what I need. Therefore I am asking here to find somebody who has experience with it to give me a hint whether this type of usage is basically possible or not.

Although this is not a typical question for this forum, I believe that it makes sense to ask since it would spare me a lot of effort and it can also help others with similar need so I hope that the community will accept this my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/):

> You can show helpful articles, videos, and web resources inside of
>   your app. Users can view web pages without leaving your app.

See also [Wrapping an existing web application in Cordova/Phonegap](https://medium.com/code-divoire/going-mobile-wrapping-an-existing-web-application-in-cordova-phonegap-106d8b60bb9a).

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed to know.